# How to pass a String pointer/reference from C++ to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, com, com-interop

I'm writing a C# com library. I need a function that takes string from C++ and modifies string, after I have modified this string in my library modified value should be usable by C++ code. Here is my function (it's not working),

C# Interface,

```
Int32 testString([param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] ref string strData);
```

C# Implementation,

```
class Test:ITest
{
  public int testString(ref string strData)
       {

            strData = strData + strData;
            Console.WriteLine("strData in lib :"+strData);
            return 0;
        }
}
```

C++ code (I missed the parts, registering com lib, importing tlb etc.),

```
ITest * mInterface = NULL;
//...initilizing interface , skipped since this parts has no problem
LPSTR tt = "OLA";
mInterface ->testString(&tt); //It crashes when comes here ..
cout << tt <<endl;
```

Comment: Usually with 3rd party DLL the string i have are limited length so i declare using this : `var mystring = new stringbuilder(1000)` for 1000 length and to pass the pointer what you usually pass is the first character as such `mystring[0]` and the dll should work fine.

Comment: C++ code, as it is written, cannot work with any C# or other function - it is just wrong. First you need to define requirements in unmanaged code. For example, write small native function that does what you want. Than write C# function that does the same. You cannot test C# function if native caller code is buggy.

Comment: @AlexFarber as I mentioned before I am using com interrup and there is no problem using c# code from c++ , i just couldnt sent my string back to c++. Thanks anyway.

Comment: C++ code passes pointer to pointer - why? Does it expect from testString to allocate a new string and return pointer to it? What should happen with original string passed to the function? tt variable points to read-only memory that cannot be modified. You need to fix the native part first.

Comment: Severe memory management issues with this code.  This won't go anywhere until you start using a BSTR in your C++ code.

Comment: @HansPassant is there any difference if a use LPStr or BSTR , I know BSTR is the default marshalling for c# strings. What happens if I change default behaviour ?

Comment: @DavutÖzcan BSTR is (a) system allocator managed, and (b) internally length-denoted, both of which are *very* helpful when marshaling. definitely worth the look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem , I am not sure but maybe we cannot initilized object from c++ to c# using com interop.If a use a null pointer to c# com , and initilize that pointer inside c# library code it worked .You can see the sample below ;

c# library interface

```
int testString(out string val);
```

c# library imp

```
class Test
{
    int testString(out string val)
    {
        val = "Hello world"; //now user of this method can use val 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

c++ usage

```
#pragma warning (disable: 4278)

#import "../yourtlb.tlb" no_namespace named_guids
ITestInterface * fpInterface = NULL;
    int retval = 1;
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Test ,
               NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
               IID_ITestInterface, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&fpInterface));

    if(!FAILED(hr))
    {
        BSTR val = NULL;
        int ret = fpInterface->testString(val);
        cout <<val<<endl;
    }
```

Of course before using code in c++ , dont forget to generate tlb file from your c# project , and dont forget to edit registry files.[Here you can see a good sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645738%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)